# How can I get the state of the shift key, down or up?

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyevent

I need to check the state of the shift key, when it is holding down or not, I do things differently.

But the

```
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

and

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSFlagsChangedMask

                                      handler:^NSEvent *(NSEvent * event)
```

I prefer to use the monitor one, but I only can get the key down event, how can I make sure if the shift key is holding down?

My rough idea is to declare a bool, and when key down, assign bool to YES, when key up, assign bool to NO.

But I can not get the key up event, does anybody know how to get the key up event, what's better, if you have a better idea, please help me thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may see how MASShortcut project handles this problem around line 400 at https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut/blob/master/Framework/MASShortcutView.m

**EDIT**

```
    NSEventMask eventMaskDown = (NSKeyDownMask | NSFlagsChangedMask);
    eventMonitorDown = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:eventMaskDown handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
        // The event object contains the key that was pressed
    }

    NSEventMask eventMaskUp = (NSKeyUpMask | NSFlagsChangedMask);
    eventMonitorUp = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:eventMaskUp handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
        // The event object contains the key that was released
    }
```

See [Modifier flags](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Modifier_Flags) for more information on Apple's website.

Comment: sorry, I want to get the callback of shift key up event, and I didn't find the answer in the link, thank you all the same.

Comment: really thanks, but how can I distinguish the key down event from the key up event. I knew both the shift key down and shift key up will call this, but I want to distinguish them, because the key down and key up I will do something different. And sorry for my poor english, hope you can catch what I want to express.

Comment: You should add one monitor for key up and one for key down. See edit.

Comment: oh I know, haha, I think I ask a stupid question.  Thanks very much.  

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just know that I should click the check to mark the accepted answer.